# Объединить строки с разных таблиц mysql

Tags: mysql

Имеется запрос:

```
SELECT worked_hours.hours, worked_hours.date, voditeli.name
FROM worked_hours
JOIN voditeli ON worked_hours.id_voditeli = voditeli.id_voditeli
WHERE worked_hours.id_tehnika = 5
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу написать запрос, так что бы можно было объединить записи по дате:

```
SELECT worked_hours.date, SUM(worked_hours.hours) as all_worked_hours, 
group_concat(distinct worked_hours.id_voditeli) as id_voditeli
FROM worked_hours
JOIN voditeli ON worked_hours.id_voditeli = voditeli.id_voditeli
WHERE worked_hours.id_tehnika = 5
GROUP BY worked_hours.date
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как сделать так, что бы во втором примере были имена вместо ID?**

Comment: `group_concat(distinct voditeli.name) as name_voditeli`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT worked_hours.date, SUM(worked_hours.hours) as all_worked_hours,         
group_concat(distinct worked_hours.id_voditeli) as id_voditeli,
group_concat(distinct voditeli.name) as name
FROM worked_hours
JOIN voditeli ON worked_hours.id_voditeli = voditeli.id_voditeli
WHERE worked_hours.id_tehnika = 5
GROUP BY worked_hours.date
```